# Accessing route URLs in the controller in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

ASP.Net MVC has some really nice features for making sure that you have the correct URL for the route you want. So I can use the `HtmlHelper` class you get the correct URL for my views:-

```
@Html.RouteLink("Link Text", new {controller = "articles", action = "tag"})
```

Now this is great. However, I find myself in the situation that I want to know the URL but I am not writing it into a view. So my question is what is the best way to get this information in the controller? I have read various posts that show you how to sneakily create an instance of `HtmlHelper` but there must be a more straightforward way of doing this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the [UrlHelper.RouteUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505226%28v=vs.108%29.aspx). `UrlHelper` is accessible via the [Url](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.url%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) property on controller.

Answer (score 0):

Controller has access to all information about the request, so Request object is where you can find the Url

```
Request.Url.ToString()
```